# How to install an application called Free DV

Tags: software-installation

I want to install an application ion to Ubuntu call FreeDV. I have been given the following instructions...

add the following to /etc/apt/sources.list (or to named /etc/apt/sources.list.d/freedv.list):

$ deb http://repo.longlandclan.id.au/{DIST} {SUITE} main

For sources, add another line with deb replaced with deb-src:

$ deb-src http://repo.longlandclan.id.au/{DIST} {SUITE} main

I assume this means a file or set of files should be copied to directories on my hard drive. I have found the directory and I have found the "Packages"  But I cannot copy or drag or extract the file(s) once they are downloaded.

Help?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

First you would I'll mention that freedv is already in the default repository of Ubuntu.  You can install something from the repository by running this in the terminal commandline:

```
$ sudo apt-get install [program to install]
```

Replace `[program to install]` with the package name.  In this case the package name is `freedv`.

So you can install freedv with this actual commandline:

```
$ sudo apt-get install freedv
```

In direct response to the specific details of you question you can add specific sites to the repository by editing the /etc/apt/sources.list and updating the cache.  You would replace the variables with your actual installation.  In my case I'm running `Ubuntu` 15.10, which is code name `wily`.

So in this case I would edit the sources list with an editor such as `gedit` with:

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Notice what is appended at the bottom of the file:

/etc/apt/sources.list:

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main restricted

# This is a comment to remind me of what is appended by me to the list
# Freedv repo
deb http://repo.longlandclan.id.au/ubuntu wily main
```

Notice that you can include your own text comments in the file to remind you what changes you have made by prefixing the line with a `#` symbol.

After saving your file you would update the cache with:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Then from there proceed to install (using the `apt-get install` command above.